# Contar o numero de registros no firebase

Tags: android, firebase, nosql, realtime-database

Bom dia Developers!
   Estou com uma dificuldade em um projeto que não consigo avançar, eis o problema/cenário:
   Temos uma tela que tráz informações, uma mensagem, e na tela existe o botão de favoritar aquela mensagem, essas informações são salvas no Firebase RealtimeDatabase, nesse cenário eu preciso dos seguintes elementos: quando o usuário clicar no imLike salvar como curtida ou descurtida dependendo da atua situação(está funcionando), toda vez verificar se aquela mensagem já havia sido curtida por aquele usuário antes(como as mensagem são geradas na tela randomicamente essa verificação se o usuário havia curtido antes deve ser feita com a mesma frequencia - está funcionando já), e por ultimo preciso que um TextView mostre quantas curtidas aquele mensagem já possui(esse eu ainda não consegui fazer).

A função abaixo é chamada logo que a activity é startada e traz os seguintes resultados: se o usuário atual já deu like naquela mensagem o image favoritar recebe a coloração vermelha e o TextView tbm.

```
private void verificarCurtida(String versiculo, String usuario) {
    String cripto = CriptografiaBase64.criptografarVersiculo(versiculo);

    likeRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReference()
            .child("VERSICULOS")
            .child(cripto)
            .child("LIKES")
            .child(usuario);

    //Verificando se esse versiculo já foi curtido antes
    likeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Pesquisando o idUsuarioe as curtidas
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
                //Se retornar valor quer dizer que já fi curtida antes por esse usuário
                imLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
                tvLikes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF1E1E"));
            } else {
                imLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
                tvLikes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

abaixo é o mesmo metodo, porém com a tentativa de adição da contagem de usuário no nó curtida:

```
private void verificarCurtida2(String versiculo, String usuario) {
    String cripto = CriptografiaBase64.criptografarVersiculo(versiculo);
    final int contar = 0;

    likeRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReference()
            .child("VERSICULOS")
            .child(cripto)
            .child("LIKES");
    //.child(usuario);

    //Verificando se esse versiculo já foi curtido antes
    likeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Pesquisando o idUsuarioe as curtidas
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
                for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    if (data.getValue().equals(preferencias.getCHAVE_ID())){
                        //Se retornar valor quer dizer que já fi curtida antes por esse usuário
                        imLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
                        tvLikes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF1E1E"));
                        contar++;

                    } else {
                        imLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
                        tvLikes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                        contar++;
                    }

                }
                //tvLikes.setText((int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    tvLikes.setText(contar);

}
```

Abaixo, segue a estrutura no firebase, onde eu tenho os seguintes nós: VERSICULOS > IDVERSICULO > LIKES > ID's dos usuários que clicaram no like;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

conforme imagem eu preciso do seguinte resultado:
VERSICULOS > IDVERSICULO > LIKES > 3 (o TextView recebe 3).

Comment: `//tvLikes.setText((int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount())` o que acontece aqui?

Answer (score 2):

Ok.
Sua referencia aponta para ("likes"), que tem 3 child's, correto?

Faça isso...

Aponte sua referencia para um nó atrás, se ele for o primeiro deixe vazio ...db.getReference();

daí segue abaixo...

```
referencia.addValeEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

         Likes likes = dataSnapshot.getvalue(Likes.class);
         //o numero de nó da referencia vai ser o tamanho do arrayList retornado
         int nChilds = likes.likes.size();
}
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
```

A classe Likes ficaria assim...

```
Class Likes{
     //o nome do arraylist deve ser o mesmo do nó pai******
     publlic ArrayList<String> likes;
}
```